# Combine five Do Until Loops into one loop Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on some excel VBA code that adds a line to an invoice document for every line of user input and copies each line of user input to that document. I have created 5 identical Do Until loops (I only use one as an example, but they are all the same aside from which column they use).

How can I combine the five loops into one loop that will:

1. Go through a column and create a line on another sheet for each user inputted item
2. Copy that text to the newly generated row
3. Once the loop reaches a blank cell in a column, it moves to the next column

Any recommendations on proper code format are also welcome as I am mostly self-taught in VBA.

Below is my code:

```
Dim Invoice As Worksheet
Set Invoice = Sheets("Generated Invoice")
Case1Start = 1
CheckRow = 20
BottomRow = 32

Do Until InputForm.Cells(CheckRow, Case1Start) = ""
Worksheets("Generated Invoice").Rows(BottomRow).EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

Invoice.Cells(BottomRow - 1, 2).Value = InputForm.Cells(CheckRow, Case1Start)
BottomRow = BottomRow + 1
CheckRow = CheckRow + 1
Loop
```

Comment: What stops you from creating another for loop for the columns?

Comment: It's a little unclear exactly what you're trying to do.  Can you provide some sample data and expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `private sub` to fire the `function` everytime

```
Private Sub autofill() {
  // Your loop
}
```